# How to store hyphen/dash in Oracle Varchar2

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to store some text with a hyphen aka dash (-) in Oracle 12c Varchar2 field.
But when I go to do a Select on the table value, the hyphen/dash character results in a funny looking symbol. I have tried escaping before using the dash (-) but that still produced the funny looking symbol. 
How do i store hypens/dashes properly in Oracle?
Thank you

Comment: You just put a dash in single quotes -- nothing special.  I suggest you post your insert/update code -- there is something wrong there.

Comment: For this kind of problem, the most likely suspect is a non-standard dash. For example, in typography, in addition to hyphens there are en-dashes and em-dashes, which may appear in non-standard positions in different character sets. To find out EXACTLY what is stored in your database, you may run `select dump(column_name) from table_name`  - that will show you the character codes; and the character set of your database.

Answer (score 0):

Putting as answer as for comment it would be too long.

First you have to establish the problem is with inserting `dash` or while fetching it. To verify, run this on the column

```
select * from table where column like '%-%';
```

If you get output, that means it is stored properly. So the problem is with displaying it.

If you don't get ouput, that means you are not inserting it properly. In that case show your insert statement. You just have to treat dash as any other string character.

Answer (score 0):

try updating that varchar field with something like below query

update tablename set columnname1='abcd'||'-' where columnname2=123;

and check if hyphen symbol is coming back

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).